# Facebook Login Alternative Solution to setFragment

Tags: android, facebook, callback

**MainActivity.java**

```
LoginFragment _loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    _loginFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**LoginFragent.java**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

At the top I have 1 main activity and a fragment to control my Facebook Login, it turn out that after pressing the button the apps crash on this two class.. How to solve this issues as the use of

> android.support.v4.app.fragemt

is not an option for me.

Comment: Did you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android ?

Comment: @PankajKumar yes i did, it needs the use of android.support.v4.app.fragemt, that needs me change the whole application import and code... so it is not an option for me.